# Aborting job in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Actually I want to extract a single column from CSV file which I already stored in a rdd and I used this code val csvArray = filerdd.map(line =>{ val colArray = line.split(",") List (colArray(13)) }...... After this code I printed that csvArray.foreach(println) ..I got the output and as well as error comes in between arrayindexoutofboundexception:13)

Comment: This shows that you are calling an index 13 while the array you are calling have a size inferior to 13.
To debug the issue, check your job log in the Spark UI. By default, you can access it using  http://localhost:4040/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code rather than use comments